# SMTP: Remote client not responding to 220

Tags: sockets, server, smtp

Recently I've been experimenting with a simple script that listens on port 25, and receives and logs any incoming emails.

It's a very primitive script, and it doesn't implement the SMTP protocol at all. It just simply spits out canned replies, and it works something like this:

1. Wait for an incoming socket.
2. Send "220 example.com ESMTP Postfix".
3. Receive one line, typically like "EHLO other.com".
4. Send "250 example.com, I am pleased to meet you".
5. Receive lines until "DATA", reply with "250 Ok" every time".
6. Send "354 End data with .".
7. Receive lines until "." is received.
8. Send 250 Ok: queued as 12345.
9. Receive any final lines then close the socket.

(example.com is in place of my real domain's FQDN.)

It's a very crude script indeed; however, for the past few months it's worked perfectly for every email that I needed to receive. I can receive fine from Gmail, Protonmail, verification emails, etc. I also caught some internet-wide scans, so it serves as a fun honeypot too.

Today, I tried to receive a Microsoft account verification email to register a Microsoft account. The remote client didn't seem to respond to the 220 at all!

```
# nc -l -v -p 25
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 25)
Connection from mail-co1nam03on0003.outbound.protection.outlook.com 56725 received!
220 example.com ESMTP Postfix
```

No matter what I tried, the client wouldn't send anything. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this belongs in here or Serverfault. I'm posting it here since I'm trying to write a script to emulate a primitive SMTP server.

Comment: Are you using LF or CRLF line terminators?

Comment: Looks like it's using LF.

# nc -l -v -p 12345 | xxd
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 12345)
Connection from localhost 40234 received!
00000000: 5468 6973 2069 7320 6120 6e65 776c 696e  This is a newlin
00000010: 650a 5a6f 6f6d 207a 6f6f 6d0a 5a4f 6f6d  e.Zoom zoom.ZOom
00000020: 207a 6f6f 6d0a 0a0a                       zoom...

Comment: Yeah, I'll try changing the \n to \r\n in my script. thanks

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Silly me for not reading the RFC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tripleee solved this in the comments, so I'm posting it as an answer here for everyone to see. The problem is that I was giving just LF as a newline, not CRLF. So I replaced all the '\n' with '\r\n' in my code, and that fixed it. I guess the other mailservers were just being lenient with me.

Comment: Glad I could help. You'll want to mark this answer as accepted so future visitors who are looking for unresolved questions don't spend time on a question which is actually resolved.